# How to display custom content in post with category XXX

Tags: posts, categories

Let’s say I have one post with tittle "Dummy one" and that post is filed under "Category one" and i have other post eg : "dummy two, dummy tree, etc" and category two, category three etc.

and now I create other post with title "helper for category one"
how to display permalink to "helper for category one" in all post with  "category one"

I want to put it under `the_content();` in `single.php`.

Let’s say my `single.php` is like this

```
if( have_post()):
while( blah blah ):
the_content();
endwhile;
endif;
```

i want to like this.

```
if():
while():
the_content();
if(category == "category one"):
display_helper_for_category_one
else:
display_nothink
endif;
endwhile;
endif;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that. You can use get_category_link for it.

```
if():
while():
the_content();
if(category == "category one"){
   // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'helper for category one' ); //get_cat_ID('category_name');

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

    // Print category link here
}
else{
   display_nothink
}
endif;
endwhile;
endif;
```

You can also use action/filter if you dont have direct access to single.php file

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress post loop, you can use the following function:

```
if ( in_category( 'pachyderms' )) {
// display_helper_for_category_one
} else {
// display_nothink
}
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category